# Build Boost Python with HDF5

Tags: c++, boost, hdf5, boost-python

I have a C++ program which deals with HDF5 files, so when compiling it, actually I need to use compiler h5c++ instead of g++. Now I want to create a Boost.Python binding for this C++ program. So I followed [the Boost.Build instructions](http://www.boost.org/build/tutorial.html) and created Jamfiles. Now I invoke the build system by

```
b2 toolset=h5c++
```

and the error is

> h5c++.jam: No such file or directory
>   /home/kevin/apps/sources/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using
>   ERROR: rule "h5c++.init" unknown in module "toolset".

I know that It won't work unless I specify something, or rebuild Boost to support h5c++, but I just have no clue of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

After trying for a whole day, I figured out one solution.

- First, h5c++ provides a flag option '-show', which enables you to find out what libraries that h5c++ is actually linking to.
- Second, based on what you find in the first step. Define variables **H5FLAGS** and **H5LIB**. In my case is

  constant H5FLAGS : "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security" ;

  constant H5LIB : "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl_cpp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_cpp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -lpthread -lz -ldl -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" ;
- Third, add the following rule to the building features

  `<cxxflags>"$(H5FLAGS)"  <linkflags>"$(H5LIB)"`

Now it is time to trigger the building system

```
b2
```